# How to import custom class from a python file having multiple classes

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a python class,myclass.py which contains 2 classes.

```
class MyTestClass1:
    def test1(self):
        print "Test 1"

class MyTestClass2:
    def test1(self):
        print "Test 1"
```

I want to implement both classes in robot framework
How to implement it ?

I tried something like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library myclass.MyTestClass1
Library myclass.MyTestClass2

*** Test Cases ***
Test Case 1
    log  This is test case 1
```

ERROR :Importing test library 'myclass.MyClass1' failed: ImportError: No module named myclass

Comment: You've misspelled the names. In myclass.py you have `MyTestCalss2` and `MyTestCalss2`, but in your robot file you use `MyTest1` and `MyTest2`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bryan but this is a typo. In my actual code this is proper.

Comment: You need to show code that actually illustrates the problem. I can't see what's on your computer.

Comment: "What you tried to do" is not a python code. Is that meant to be pseudo-code?? Please append the whole code you tried, as it can't be much for this simple example...

Comment: I have a python class file which I want to use inside my Robot Framework.The above example contains one python file having two classes and i m trying to implement these classes in robot framework.

Comment: When you fix the typo in the code in your question, it works just fine. So, the answer to your question is "fix the typo". If your question has no relationship to your real problem, there's nothing we can do about that.

Comment: Bryan there is no typo in my code.I have posted my actual code above and I am getting the below error  : [ ERROR ] Error in file '/root/vaibhav/RobotFramework/library/test.robot': Importing test library 'myclass.MyClass1' failed: ImportError: No module named myclass

Comment: You still have a similar problem. In the python file you have `MyTestClass1`, but in the robot file you're using `MyTest1`. The names must be the same. You also have the problem that you need at least one more space after `Library`.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry I m so dumb that didn't noticed this small mistake.I will fix this and try again.Thanks a lot @BryanOakley for pointing this out

Comment: @BryanOakleyStill getting the same error :Importing test library 'myclass.MyClass1' failed: ImportError: No module named myclass

Comment: The way I'm trying to use the python class as Library , is that Correct ?

Comment: If you're getting "no module named myclass", that just means that `myclass.py` isn't in your PYTHONPATH. This is all described in the robot user guide. See http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#configuring-where-to-search-libraries-and-other-extensions

Comment: Correct @BryanOakley but I am not sure why this error is even comming as both my python module and .robot file are in same directory.So the first search should be done in the current directory.Also I have gone through the docs and the way I'm trying to import the lib is as per docs only http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-libraries

Comment: @BryanOakleyThanks for help !!! This actually solved my problem robot --pythonpath /root/vaibhav/RobotFramework/library/ test.robot

Comment: @MilanVaibhav did you find any other way to use it other than specifying the pythonpath in robot command, as in to mention path while using Library keyword or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your code only

**Python file  Myclass.py**

```
class MyTestClass1:
    def test1(self):
        print "Test 1"

class MyTestClass2:
    def test1(self):
        print "Test 1"
```

**Robot File**

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Myclass.MyTestClass1
Library    Myclass.MyTestClass2

*** Test Cases ***
Test Case 1
    log  This is test case 1
```

Run it

Output

```
==============================================================================
Myclassf
==============================================================================
Test Case 1                                                           | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Myclassf                                                              | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

**Possible issue with your execution**

1) Your robot file and Python file may not be in same folder ( its not necessary, but then you have to specify the path if both the files are at different location

2)You need to take lower/upper case in mind while giving the filename/classname in Library

Comment: I am at same point.  Get the testcase pass but the errors are found-
log file -
(venv) C:\temp\robo>robot myrobo.robot
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\temp\robo\myrobo.robot': Importing test library 'Myclass.MyTestClass1' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Myclass'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  None
PYTHONPATH:
  C:\Tools\WorkSpace\PycharmProjects\RobotFramework\venv\Scripts\robot.exe
  C:\Tools\Python37\python37.zip
  C:\Tools\Python37\DLLs
  C:\Tools\Python37\lib
  C:\Tools\Python37
  c:\tools\workspace\pycharmprojects\robotframework\venv
  c:\tools\workspace\.....

Comment: are python and robotfile is in same folder ?

Comment: Yes. Both are in same folder.
C:\TEMP\ROBO
    Myclass.py
    myrobo.robot